# Accessing json string in java and creating hashmap Android

Tags: java, android, json, hashmap

I have a JSON string and I am trying to retrieve information from it. Json String looks like this.

JSON STRING :

```
{
    "information": {
        "device": {
            "id": 0
        },
        "user": {
            "id": 0
        },
        "data": [
            {
                "datum": {
                    "id": "00GF001",
                    "history_id": "9992BH",
                    "name": "abc",
                    "marks": 57,
                    "class": "B",
                    "type": "Student"
                }
            },
            {
                "datum": {
                    "id": "72BA9585",
                    "history_id": "78NAH2",
                    "name": "ndnmanet",
                    "marks": 70,
                    "class": "B",
                    "type": "Student"
                }
            },
            {
                "datum": {
                    "id": "69AHH85",
                    "history_id": "NN00E3006",
                    "name": "kit",
                    "department": "EF003",
                    "class": "A",
                    "type": "Employee"
                }
            },
            {
                "datum": {
                    "id": "09HL543",
                    "history_id": "34QWFTA",
                    "name": "jeff",
                    "department": "BH004",
                    "class": "A1",
                    "type": "Employee_HR"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am trying to access data JSONArray and respective Datum from it. I differentiated each datum as per type such as student, employee etc and push information in hashmap. 
I successfully did it in javascript but in Java I am struggle abit.

When I am trying to access JSONArray it throws exception

```
 try {
            JSONObject data = new JSONObject(dataInfo);
           // Log.d(TAG, "CHECK"+data.toString());
         JSONObject info = data.optJSONObject("information");
            if(info.getJSONArray("data").getString(0).equals("Student") > 0)  //exception here

                Log.d(TAG, "Data"+ data.getJSONArray("data").length()); //exception here too
            for(int m = 0; m < data.length(); m++){
                //   for(int s = 0; s < data[m].ge)
            }
        } catch (JSONException j){
            j.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Any pointers to create hashmap respective type I have. Appreciated

Comment: The code you have provided does not have enough information to fully help you here. For example, what is `current`? Unless I am missing something, there is no `"signals"` within the JSON you are getting back?

Comment: I have made edit sorry, but how can I access the type from this json string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to access the `type` field of a `datum` object, you'll want something like this:

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject(dataInfo); // get the entire JSON into an object
JSONObject info = data.getJSONObject("information"); // get the 'information' object
JSONArray dataArray = info.getJSONArray("data"); // get the 'data' array

for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length(); i++) {
    // foreach element in the 'data' array
    JSONObject dataObj = dataArray.getJSONObject(i); // get the object from the array
    JSONObject datum = dataObj.getJSONObject("datum"); // get the 'datum' object
    String type = datum.getString("type"); // get the 'type' string

    if ("Student".equals(type)) {
        // do your processing for 'Student' here
    }
}
```

Note that you'll have to deal with exception handling, bad data, etc. This code just shows you the basics of how to get at the data that you're looking for. I separated each individual step into its own line of code so that I could clearly comment what is happening at each step, but you could combine some of the steps into a single line of code if that is easier for you.

Comment: Thanks I got bit confused and messedup  in following the hierarchy from json origin json String. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if dataInfo is the json you posted, then you have to access information and from information, you can access data:

```
 JSONObject data = new JSONObject(dataInfo);
 JSONObject info = data.optJSONObject("information");
 if (info != null) {
    JSONArray dataArray = info.optJSONArray("data")
 }
```